# Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I had a similar issue two weeks ago where I couldn't paste data from SQL, and the solution suggested was to export it because it wasn't possible to paste that many rows (153,000).

However, I've got a query for which the results are significantly smaller - 416 rows and 4 columns, but I still get the same 'Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data' error message.

It's possible to do it from a different laptop, however.

I've tried to clear the clipboard on the laptop with the problem, but that doesn't fix it!

Has anyone else experienced this? And is there another solution, besides exporting the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [SQL Operations Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download), where you can save directly to Excel, or save result table to text and import it to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

From excel, you should be able to use MS SQL Query to pull the data from the database into an Excel table.  May be easier than using the clipboard (and almost certainly faster)

Comment: ..or even better and put Power Pivot to work if you have it available.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error when trying to copy data from a DataGridView in my winforms c# program and pasting it into excel. I got around it by pasting the data into Notepad++ first, then copied the data in Notepad++ and pasted it into excel.

Comment: This shows that the problem could be down to meta data and/or formatting. +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can paste it into txt file, copy from it and paste to excel. However, then you need to uses "Data To Columns" function, because excel will paste it into one column.